# Как минифицировать нормалайз?

Tags: webpack

У меня есть scss файл основной.
В нем подключаются другие файлы, содержатся стили и полключен нормалайз

```
@import 'normalize.css';
@import 'fonts';
@import 'reset';
@import 'var';
```

Ниже под этим указываю другие стили.
Когда делаю билд сборку вебпак, минифицируется все кроме нормалайз цсс. Как мне его минифицировать то же?
Пробовал в test указать (s[c|a]ss|css), не помогло

```
{
  test: /.(s[c|a]ss|css)$/,
  use: [
  {
    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
  }, 
  {
    loader: 'css-loader'
  },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: [
          autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ['ie >= 8', 'last 4 version']
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    loader: 'sass-loader'
  }],
}
```

Comment: попробуйте его импорт сделать в js файле, думаю поможет — самое простое решение

Comment: спасибо, действительно проще всего

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял что за разрешение @импорта отвечает опция import:

(Пока с телефона — не могу проверить)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          import: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```